# Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library

Tags: flutter, dart

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

## The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

## Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
dots_indicator: ^2.0.0
firebase_auth: ^1.2.0
cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0
firebase_core: ^1.2.0
provider: ^5.0.0
geolocator: ^7.0.3
google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.5
geocoder: ^0.2.1
flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

Comment: This is not possible without either migrating entire code to nul safety or fixing the part of your code that is trying to use null safety feature. Post you code where the issue is coming.

Comment: if( user! = null){
                   print(this.screen);

Comment: when i start running its showing error at user

Comment: Update your question with your code of this widget.

Comment: please check it!

Comment: There is a problem in your pubsec.yaml file. Add that as well.

Comment: added please check it

Answer (score 0):

All of your dependencies are their latest versions and all of them have migrated to `null safety`.

Since you cannot intermix both `null safe` and `non null safe` packages together, you would need to migrate your code to code to `null safety`.

First, change your sdk as such,

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Then run `pub get` (this automatically runs once you save the file but you can run it if it doesn't automatically)

Next, migrate your code wherever necessary to use the new null safe features.

Comment: ?? what happened ?

Comment: i am unable to do migration i am getting too many errors

Comment: Pick them up one by one. Start with the first one. Read up on null safety a bit more.  https://dart.dev/null-safety/ It might take a bit of time, but you will get through it.